# CSS: how to color all the words between ‘ and ’

Tags: css

i was looking for a way to color in a page all the words between ‘ and  ’ .not manually

i already tried with:

```css
em, q {quotes: "‘" "’"; color: B8FEFF;}
```

seems i can't get it right.

How do I do this strictly with CSS?

Edit: if strictly with CSS is not possible, how is it with javascript?

Comment: You can not style Elements based on their content.

Comment: You have a typo you should write it  : `color:#B8FEFF`  . **#** is missing at `B8FEFF` . https://jsfiddle.net/z9Lq1xyd/

Comment: @G-Cyrillus that is not really the issue here.

Comment: It is not possible to do this strictly with CSS, you'll need e.g. some Javascript to look through the text.

Comment: @AHaworth then how would it be with javascript?

Comment: Not the issue ? , so what is your HTML ? Your selector is for em/q tags, both take color rules fine  (em won't produce those quotes BTW) -|-  B8FEFF is not a valid color name. Can you clarify your question with the HTML you are trying to style.

Comment: Ah @G-Cyrillus, yes, sounds like I may have misinterpreted. Please show the HTML because if you've got certain elements in there it may be possible.

Comment: ;) @AHaworth . I turned the CSS sample into a snippet, so piraxxo can easily add the HTML to be styled and demonstrate the issue.